# HTML content filling page, but able to scroll past to other content

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make it so that on the homepage of my site, when I load into the site, you can only see the nav, title, image and some text underneath, the red div elements should not be shown, and you would have to scroll down to see it. How do I do this while still making the page responsive?

```css
h2 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

h3 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
}

body {}

img {
  height: 10%;
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  float: left;
  padding: 1%;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

li a.active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.nav {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
}


/*text that needs to stay on home page under image*/

.text {
  text-align: center;
}


/*what needs to be hidden*/

.container1 {
  padding: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}


/*Area with title and image*/

.header {
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  grid-area: banner;
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .leftcolumn,
  .rightcolumn {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200,400" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Learning Journal</a></li>
    <li>Tutorial</li>
    <li>Contact Me</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="header">
  <h2> CI435 - INTRODUCTION TO WEB DEVELEPMONT</h2>
  <img src="images/htmlcode.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div class="text">
  <h2>PLACEHOLDER</h2>
</div>
<div class="container1">
  <h3>Weeek x</h3>
  <p> PLACEHOLDER</p>
</div>

<div class="container1">
  <h3>Weeek x</h3>
  <p> PLACEHOLDER</p>
</div>
<div class="container1">
  <h3>Weeek x</h3>
  <p> PLACEHOLDER</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Where are the red div elements in the code? It might be good to comment the code a bit.

Comment: Assuming you want this to be the case on every screen, you could wrap the elements you want visible in a div and give it a height of 100vh

Comment: @rpivovar just added some comments,

Comment: @SamJohnson that seemed to work, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `height: 100vh` (the viewport unit).

You'll also need to wrap your `.header` and `.text` placeholder into a parent element so you can control the height. I've wrapped it into the `<main class="full-height"` element and styled the class `.full-height { height: 100vh; }`

Now the user is forced to scroll to the red no matter how big/small there device is.

```css
h2 {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}

h3 {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;
}

body {}

img {

    height: 10%;
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;


}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;

}

li {
    float: left;
    padding: 1%;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

li a {

    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;

}

li a.active {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.nav {

    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: white;
}

.text {

    text-align: center;
}

.container1 {

    padding: 40px;
    background-color: brown;
    text-align: center;
}


.header {
    padding: 30px;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    grid-area: banner;
    width: 100%;

    color: black;
}

.full-height { height: 100vh; }


@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {

    .leftcolumn,
    .rightcolumn {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Learning Journal</a></li>
            <li>Tutorial</li>
            <li>Contact Me</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

 <main class="full-height">
  <div class="header">
   <h2> CI435 - INTRODUCTION TO WEB DEVELEPMONT</h2>
   <img src="images/htmlcode.jpg" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="text">
   <h2>PLACEHOLDER</h2>
  </div>
 </main>

    <div class="container1">
        <h3>Weeek x</h3>
        <p> PLACEHOLDER</p>
    </div>

    <div class="container1">
        <h3>Weeek x</h3>
        <p> PLACEHOLDER</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container1">
        <h3>Weeek x</h3>
        <p> PLACEHOLDER</p>
    </div>
```